# JavaScript: alert object name as a string

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to `alert` any JavaScript object as a string, in a function. This means if the parameter given to the function is `window.document`, the actual object, it should alert "window.document" (without quotes) as a *literal* string.

The following calls...

```
example(window);
example(window.document);
example(document.getElementById('something'));
```

...calling this function...

> function example(o) {/* A little help here please? */}

...should output the following strings...

```
window
window.document
document.getElementById('something')
```

I've attempted to do this with combinations of `toString()` and `eval()` among some more miscellaneous shots in the dark without success.

No need insane backwards compatibility, newer ECMAScript / JavaScript features/functions are fine. Feel free to inquire for clarifications though the goal should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible to do in a self contained script.

If using a preprocessor would be an option, then you could write one which converts `example(whatever)` into `example('whatever')`. Other than that I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that *objects don't have names.*

The second problem is that from your examples, you're not really wanting to print the (nonexistent) name of an object, you want to print the *expression* that evaluated into a reference to an object. That's what you're trying to do in this example:

```
example(document.getElementById('something'));
```

For that to print `document.getElementById('something')`, JavaScript would have had to keep the actual text of that expression somewhere that it would make available to you. But it doesn't do that. It merely evaluates the parsed and compiled expression without reference to the original text of the expression.

If you were willing to quote the argument to `example()`, then of course it would be trivial:

```
example( "document.getElementById('something')" );
```

Obviously in this case you could either print the string directly, or `eval()` it to get the result of the expression.

OTOH, if you want to try a real hack, here's a trick you could use in some very limited circumstances:

```
function example( value ) {
    var code = arguments.callee.caller.toString();
    var match = code.match( /example\s*\(\s*(.*)\s*\)/ );
    console.log( match && match[1] );
}

function test() {
    var a = (1);
    example( document.getElementById('body') );
    var b = (2);
}

test();
```

This will print what you wanted:

```
document.getElementById('body')
```

(The assignments to `a` and `b` in the `test()` function are just there to verify that the regular expression isn't picking up too much code.)

But this will fail if there's more than one call to `example()` in the calling function, or if that call is split across more than one line. Also, `arguments.callee.caller` has been deprecated for some time but is still supported by most browsers as long as you're not in strict mode. I suppose this hack could be useful for some kind of debugging purposes though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you need this, but you can try walking the object tree recursively and compare its nodes with your argument:

```
function objectName(x) {

    function search(x, context, path) {
        if(x === context)
            return path;
        if(typeof context != "object" || seen.indexOf(context) >= 0)
            return;
        seen.push(context);
        for(var p in context) {
            var q = search(x, context[p], path + "." + p);
            if(q)
                return q;
        }
    }

    var seen = [];
    return search(x, window, "window");
}
```

Example:

```
console.log(objectName(document.body))
```

prints for me

```
window.document.activeElement
```