# Get name of instance of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a code like the one bellow and want to detect the instance name of my `exScript`.

In this case it would be `exScript123`.

```
eecore = {
    something: 1,
    // ...
    someelse: function() { /* whatever */ };
};

var exScript = (function (undefined) {
    function exScript(inputOptions) {
        this.version = "0.0";
    }
    exScript.prototype.init = function () {
        // some code here
    };
    return exScript;
})();

eecore.exScript123 = new exScript();
eecore.exScript123.init();
```

I have been experimenting for the last hour with `arguments.calle.name` and `this.parent.name` but they do not seem to work in my case. I keep getting undefined.

Comment: The same object reference can be shared by several variables. In that case, if what you want to do was possible, which variable name should be returned?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question. In my case it should return `exScript123`. I need to get `exScript123` inside of the init prototype. In order to set a cookie that holds some data uniquely for this instance so it does not conflict with others.

Comment: But what if you had `eecore.exScript123 = eecore.foo = eecore.bar = new exScript()`? Should `exScript123`, `foo` or `bar` be returned (as they all point to the same object)? *(That's actually a rhetorical question, what you want to achieve is not possible in the first place.)*

Comment: The instance doesn't really have any inherent way of knowing what variable(s) it's being referenced by. Why not accept a `name` argument on the constructor so the instance has its own record of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly modified version of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877226/989121):

```
function objectName(x, context, path) {

    function search(x, context, path) {
        if(x === context)
            return path;
        if(typeof context != "object" || seen.indexOf(context) >= 0)
            return;
        seen.push(context);
        for(var p in context) {
            var q = search(x, context[p], (path ? path + "." : "") + p);
            if(q)
                return q;
        }
    }

    var seen = [];
    return search(x, context || window, path || "");
}
```

In your init function

```
    exScript.prototype.init = function () {
        console.log(objectName(this, eecore))
    };
```

correctly prints `exScript123`.

As pointed out in the comments, this is unreliable and a strange idea in general. You might want to clarify why you need that - surely there are better ways.

Comment: Not exactly a simple solution but thanks for answering. I have found a better solution for my issue.

Comment: I simply set a variable `exScriptInstance` in window that I increment each time a new instance is instantiated and store the incremented value inside a variable of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would have a need to know the/a varialbe name that points to the instance of your object. As stated before you can have several variables with different names point to the same instance.

As mentioned before; if you need a unique id or name then create that as a property of the exScript instance when you create it.

If you want to make sure that init only executes when the `this` constext is an instance of exScript you can do the following:

```
var exScript = (function (undefined) {
    function exScript(inputOptions) {
        this.version = "0.0";
    }
    exScript.prototype.init = function () {
      // you can use (this instanceof exScript)
      // that will go up the prototype chain and see
      // if the current object is an instance of or inherits from
      // exScript
      // simple check: see if this is a direct instance of exScript
      if(this.constructor!==exScript){
        console.log("no good");
        return;
      }
      console.log("ok init");
      // some code here
    };
    return exScript;
})();

var e = new exScript();
e.init();//= ok init
setTimeout(e.init,100);//= no good
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code example:

```
 function Parent(){
        // custom properties
    }

    Parent.prototype.getInstanceName = function(){
        for (var instance in window){
            if (window[instance] === this){
                return instance;
            }
        }
    };

    var child = new Parent();

    console.log(child.getInstanceName()); // outputs: "child"
```

Comment: @tntu Note: This implementation works if the instance was created in the root.